# Converting couple of integers into one integer in C

Tags: c, loops, casting

In doing an assignment, in which:

*Program prints out the sum in the form of the following text
1 + 22 + 333 + 4444 + . . . + nn. . . n }n
and its result. The number n ∈ {1, 2, . . . , 9} is provided by the user*

I'm stuck at the point where I don't know how to glue the numbers into one integer, so how to convert "333" into 333, etc.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Program calculates a sum.\nAutor: Jakub Drozd\n");
    int n;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the length of the sum (no more than 9): ");
    while (scanf_s("%d", &n)!=1 || n < 1 || getchar()!='\n')
    {
        printf("Wrong input, enter the length of the sum: ");
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1);
        else { printf(" + "); }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnd of the program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, The program correctly displays the numbers to be added, but I don't know how to cast them into integers to sum them up.

Comment: I recommend you kind of forget that `scanf` (or `scanf_s`) exists. Instead read lines using e.g. `fgets`, and then perhaps use `sscanf` to parse the string, or `strtol`. Make input and validation much simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm forced to use scanf, but I'm aware of its disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing out the individual digits, add them together to form the actual value, and then add them to a sum that you present.

The creation of the numbers could be like

```
int number = 0;
for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
{
    number = number * 10 + i;
}
```

Then adding the numbers is as simple as creating a variable to hole the sum, and adding to it:

```
int sum = 0;
// ...
sum += number;
```

Comment: Yes, 
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
 {
  int liczba = 0;
  if (i == 1);
  else
  {
   printf(" + ");
  }
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
  {
   liczba = liczba * 10 + i;
  }
  printf("%d", liczba);
  sum += liczba;
 }